# Is there any reason to not overload operator== as member, when only comparing to other object of the class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've been combing through the internet to find an answer, but I couldn't find any. The only reasons given seems to be relevant for comparing with objects of different type (e.g. `MyClass == int`). But the most common use case is comparing a class instance to another instance of the same class, not to any unrelated type.

In other words, I do understand the problems with:

```
struct A {
    bool operator==(int b);
};
```

But I cannot find any good reason to not use member function in the most obvious use-case:

```
struct A {
    bool operator==(const A&);
};
```

---

- The most canonical duplicate [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421729#4421729) says "overload binary operators as non-member" as rule of a thumb.
- [Operator overloading : member function vs. non-member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622330/operator-overloading-member-function-vs-non-member-function) gives example mentioned above - *if you were to use this operator with instance of another class/primitive type*...
- [CppCoreGuidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ro-symmetric) has a vague explanation "*If you use member functions, you need two*", which I assume applies to comparing with object of different type.
- [Why should operator< be non-member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047174/why-should-operator-be-non-member-function) mentions that "*non-member functions play better with implicit conversion*", but it seems again the case of left-hand operand not being the instance of the class.

On the other hand, member overload seems to have a couple positive sides:

- No need to befriend the function or to provide getters for members
- It is always available to class users (although this might be the downside also)
- No problems with lookup (which seems to be common in our GoogleTests for some reason)

---

**Is overloading `operator==` as non-member function just a convention to keep it the same with possible overloads in other classes? Or are there any other reasons to make it non-member?**

Comment: Unrelated, but "problems with lookup" sounds like you are losing a battle against ADL. Are you defining non-member functions that are part of the class interface in the same namespace as the class (as one should)?

Comment: [See cpp guideline C4](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c4-make-a-function-a-member-only-if-it-needs-direct-access-to-the-representation-of-a-class).

Comment: A downside with "_Make a function a member only if it needs direct access to the representation of a class_" is that as a user of a class, I would need to search for loose helper functions as well as class member functions. Code completion, typing `classname.` and waiting for my options if I've forgotten the interface goes out the window etc.

Comment: @TedLyngmo - The API of a class also belongs in the same header file under the same namespace, or in a well associated header. No damage to code completion. Also, let's not forget the open-closed principle. A class that can be extended easily by free functions is surely inline with that one.

Comment: @StoryTeller "_No damage to code completion_" - I must upgrade my `vim`:-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in your question, you did forget to `const` qualify the member function, and it would be harder to write `bool operator==(A&, const A&);` by accident.

If you had an implicit constructor, a class with implicit conversion to `A` or base class with an `operator==` with higher priority, the member function wouldn't work if it was on the left, but would if it was on the right. Although most of the time implicit conversions are a bad idea, inheritance could reasonably lead to a problem.

```cpp
struct A {
    A(int);  // Implicit constructor
    A();

    bool operator==(const A&) const;
};

struct B : A {
    bool operator==(const B&) const;
};

void test() {
    A a;
    B b;
    // 1 == a;  // Doesn't work
    a == 1;
    // b == a;  // Doesn't work; Picks `B::operator==(const B&) const;`
    a == b;  // Picks `A::operator==(const A&) const`, converting `b` to an `A&`.
    // Equality is no longer symmetric as expected
}
```

---

In the future, with the C++20 `operator<=>`, you will most likely always implement this as a member function (namely as [`auto operator<=>(const T&) const = default;`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons)), so we know that this guideline may change.

Comment: Oh yes. The symmetric behaviour of implicit conversions is stronger than just stylistic argument.

Answer (score 6):

The arguments for using non-member operator overload for symmetric operations are based on style and consistency. They are not very strong arguments <sup>1</sup>. Non-member overloads are typically preferred because a weak argument is still a little bit better than no argument at all.

Your arguments for member operator overload don't seem to be any stronger. Consider following:

> No need to befriend the function

On the other hand, if you use a non-member overload, then you don't have need to declare a member function. Is befriending the non-member somehow worse?

> or to provide getters for members

There is no need for that if you befriend the overload.

> It is always available to class users (although this might be the downside also)

It is unclear how this differs from the non-member overloads. Are they also not always available to the class users?

> No problems with lookup (which seems to be common in our GoogleTests for some reason)

Are there lookup problems with non-member overloads? Could you demonstrate the problem with an example, and show how the problem is solved by using a member overload instead?

If it does solve the problem, then you can of course use that. Just because some guidelines recommend that you prefer one alternative as a rule of thumb, doesn't mean that is the only alternative to be used in all use cases.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57927564/2079303 which is arguably stronger than just stylistic.

Comment: Problem with lookup might happen with misplaced functions (not in same namespace than the class). Member cannot be outside the class :)